# across function not found in dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I want to use the `across()` function in `dplyr` but get an error. For instance, running

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean))
```

gives me

```
Error in across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean) : 
  could not find function "across"
```

`across()` is a recent introduction https://towardsdatascience.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-new-dplyr-1-0-0-7eaaaf6d78ac in `dplyr`. However, the package `dplyr` is updated and loaded

```
packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘1.0.0’
```

Checking inside `dplyr`

```
ls("package:dplyr")
  [1] "%>%"                   "add_count"             "add_count_"            "add_row"               "add_rownames"          "add_tally"            
  [7] "add_tally_"            "all_equal"             "all_vars"              "anti_join"             "any_vars"              "arrange"              
 [13] "arrange_"              "arrange_all"           "arrange_at"            "arrange_if"            "as_data_frame"         "as_label"
```

I find that `across` does not exist, however if I look the function up in the helper `?across` I get the classic page explaining the functionalities of `across`.

How to get `across` to work?

----- EDIT -----

My `sessionInfo()` is as follows:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyselect_1.1.0 dplyr_1.0.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.2     compiler_3.6.1   forcats_0.4.0    tools_3.6.1      jsonlite_1.6     lubridate_1.7.4  lifecycle_0.2.0 
[10] tibble_2.1.3     nlme_3.1-140     gtable_0.3.0     lattice_0.20-38  pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.6      cli_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.10  haven_2.1.1     
[19] xml2_1.2.2       httr_1.4.1       stringr_1.4.0    generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.3.1      hms_0.5.1        grid_3.6.1       glue_1.4.1       R6_2.4.0        
[28] fansi_0.4.0      readxl_1.3.1     readr_1.3.1      modelr_0.1.5     tidyr_1.0.0      purrr_0.3.3      ggplot2_3.2.1    magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.4 
[37] scales_1.0.0     rvest_0.3.4      assertthat_0.2.1 tidyverse_1.2.1  colorspace_1.4-1 utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.4.3    lazyeval_0.2.2   munsell_0.5.0   
[46] broom_0.5.2      crayon_1.3.4    
> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library"
```

Comment: If you call it more explicitly with `dplyr::across` does it work?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. `Error: 'across' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'`

Comment: Is dplyr 1.0.0 listed in your sessionInfo after you load the package?  I'm wondering if you have another version of dplyr somewhere else that is causing problems.  Maybe also add your OS info; I can't reproduce the problem in Windows 7 R 4.0.

Comment: `dplyr 1.0.0` is displyed under `other attached packages:` together with `tidyselect_1.1.0`. I'm running this on `Mac`. I don't know how to have other people reproducing this error (the code comes from the `across` help page)

Comment: I attached the session info and `.libPath()` output to my question

Comment: Appears to work on my system (recently updated R and all packages). Did you try updating packages and restarting first? Then maybe update to R 4.0.1? Might not solve but worth a try?

Answer (score 2):

The across function is available only in the development version of dplyr, not on CRAN yet
to use the accross function install dplyr dev version by using the code below

```
install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
library(dplyr)
```

now your code should work

```
data("iris")
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), mean))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
  <fct>             <dbl>       <dbl>
1 setosa             5.01        3.43
2 versicolor         5.94        2.77
3 virginica          6.59        2.97
```

Comment: It is available since dplyr 1.0.0, see https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/04/dplyr-1-0-0-colwise/